# Struts 2 Dynamic Url to be used in Search

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

How to treat URL string as parameter without having the "?" character after the action name?

Let's say for example we have usernames from database: jr, jack, j, etc...

What I want is to view their profile using domain.com/user/jr, domain.com/user/jack, domain.com/user/j, etc.

Is there a way for these?

From the example, jr, jack, j are dynamic and the key to be used in viewing their profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[Wildcard mappings](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/wildcard-mappings.html)**.

An example for **Action Annotations** (Convention Plugin) :

`struts.xml`

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
```

---

```
@Action(value = "user/{userName}", results = {
        @Result(location = "user.jsp")
})
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

    private String userName; // with getter & setter

    public void prepare() {
        // getUserByUserName(userName)
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the Struts 2 REST plug-in, since you're looking for REST-style URLs.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html

I don't remember if having the plug-in replaces the normal 'action' class mapping, but I think it might.  That is, I think after having it present, all your actions have to be mapped by convention as specified in the info I linked.

Good luck.